# how to use if statement for function with pre-defined argument

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, yield

This is my code:

```
def characters(a=''):
    if a:
        for c in Characters:
            b=c
            print(b)
    else:
        for char in Characters:
            yield char
```

What I want is, whenever function is called without argument it should print the keys inside dictionary "Characters" and when argument is given it should return the keys instead of printing them.
The else statement does it's job but if statement doesn't work.

Comment: Is `Characters` a dictionary or list?

Comment: it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` is the wrong way around – the empty string is falsy in Python's eyes.

However, maybe instead of "without argument" you might want an argument default value with some semantics?

```
def characters(mode='print'):
    if mode == 'print':
        for c in Characters:
            print(c)
    elif mode == 'yield':
        for char in Characters:
            yield char
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid mode')
```

This way `characters()` defaults to printing, `characters('print')` does the same, and `characters('yield')` does the other thing (and other values cause an exception).

Comment: The answer below worked , but this method still doesn't work. when i used characters()/characters('print') there is no response, characters('yield') seems to work fine tho..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
def characters(a=""):
    character_keys = list(Characters.keys())
    if a:
        return character_keys
    else:
        print(character_keys)
```

Comment: Please note that this solution only works, if `dict` Characters is accessible on a "global" level within your code (a.k.a most likely for you 0-indention or within `if __name__ == "__main__":`). If that is not the case, you would have to pass `Characters` as a parameter to the function.